# How do I generate a sprited image file with Compass?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, css-sprites

#### Background

I have a directory of images, `app/assets/images/sprites/flags/*.png` that will be sprited. Compass, Sass, and Sprockets work together such that I can put

```
@import "sprites/flags/*.png";
...
.flag.en {
  @include flags-sprite(en)
}
```

in my `.scss` file. By doing so, Compass generates the file `app/assets/images/sprites/flags-abc123.png` when I compile SCSS files.

#### Problem

I would like to *precompile* that `flags-abc123.png` file via a Rake task or shell command **without compiling my `.scss` file**. Is there a way to do so?

#### Rationale

Compiling all of the `.scss` files in the application is a lengthy part of the deploy process. We would like to speed up deploys by generating them on one machine and distributing them. Unfortunately, the other machines generate bad cache-busting URLs because they are missing the compiled sprite files. If we can precompile the sprite files, we can speed up deploys dramatically.

#### What I tried

I tried running `bundle exec compass sprite app/assets/images/sprites/flags/*.png`. That generates `app/assets/stylesheets/_flags.scss`, but doesn't generate `app/assets/images/sprites/flags-abc123.png`.

Comment: Can you add your config.rb of compass project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a Rake task:

```
class SpriteTask
  include Rake::DSL

  attr_reader :file_task

  def initialize(glob)
    @glob = glob
    build_compass_sprite_map
    define_task
  end

  private

  attr_reader :glob, :map

  def build_compass_sprite_map
    uri = Sass::Script::String.new(glob)
    context = Object.new
    kwargs = {}
    kwargs.extend Compass::SassExtensions::Functions::Sprites::VariableReader
    @map = Compass::SassExtensions::Sprites::SpriteMap.from_uri uri, context, kwargs
    @map.options = {}
  end

  def define_task
    @file_task = file(map.filename => map.image_filenames) do |task|
      map.generate
    end
  end
end
```

and using it like so:

```
require 'sprite_task'
namespace :sprites do
  task :generate do
    SpriteTask.new('foo/*.png').file_task.invoke
    SpriteTask.new('bar/*.png').file_task.invoke
  end
end
```